# Why would JSRuntime.InvokeAsync fail when IEnumerable<MyClass<T>> is passed to it, when T is not string?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, blazor, blazor-client-side

Running the latest Blazor preview release, client-side, I have an application that loads an `IEnumerable<MyClass<T>> data` of a simple generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I pass this `IEnumerable` to `JSRuntime.InvokeAsync` like so:

`await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("renderChart", data);`

When T is type `string`, this works as expected. When T is type `double` or `float` it fails with errors:

```
WASM: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.    
WASM:   at System.Text.Json.ReflectionMemberAccessor+<>c__DisplayClass11_0`2[TClass,TProperty].<CreatePropertyGetter>b__0 (System.Object obj) <0x2951800 + 0x0000c> in <e1cfca862e6a44dbaac6737c11b98f37>:0`
```

The JavaScript function does nothing more than log the value:

```
function renderChart(data) {
    console.log("Data:", data);
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Log it as a bug on github. It should work.